# Counting question - binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Why is there a difference in choosing $2$ out of $n$ elements and after that $2$ out of the $n-2$ remaining elements compared to choosing $4$ elements. So why is, intuitively (not algebraically), ${n \choose 2} \cdot {n-2 \choose 2} \cdot \dfrac{1}{2}\neq {n \choose 4}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first method selects two groups of two and not one of four. So $\{a,b,c,d\}$ could be $\{a,b\}\{c,d\}$, or $\{a,c\}\{b,d\}$, and so on.

In fact, we have:

$$\binom{n}{2}\binom{n-2}{2}=\binom{n}{4}\binom{4}{2}$$

Comment: Possible mistake, re overcounting.  See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

With $\binom n2\binom{n-2}2/2$ you are choosing four elements, but then you are splitting that selection into two unordered groups of two. Hence it is doing more than merely selecting four elements ($\binom n4$), and produces a larger number.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $n=6$, and assume that set $S = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}.$

Consider the specific collection of 4 items represented by the subset $T = \{1,2,3,4\}.$

There are 3 distinct ways of partitioning set $T$ into two pairs: $\{(1,2),(3,4)\}$, $\{(1,3),(2,4)\}$, and $\{(1,4),(2,3)\}$.

This means that since there are $\binom{6}{4} = 15$ ways of forming a collection of four items (similar to subset $T$) from set $S$, there are $(3 \times 15) = 45$ ways of partitioning set $S$ into two distinct pairs, with two items left over.

Superficially, you would expect that the # of ways of forming the two distinct pairs from set $S$ would be 
$\displaystyle \binom{6}{4} \times \binom{4}{2}$, (which is wrong) 
rather than $\displaystyle \binom{6}{4} \times \binom{4}{2} \times \frac{1}{2}$, (which is right).  The last factor, $\frac{1}{2}$, which is an *overcounting adjustment scalar* is needed, because otherwise each of the partitions into two pairs would be double counted.

As an illustration of this, note that the partitioning of set $T$ above, into $2$ pairs could only be done in $3$ ways, even though $\binom{4}{2} = 6.$

In general, there will be $\binom{n}{4}$ ways of forming collections of $4$ items from a set of $n$ items, and there will be 
$\displaystyle \binom{n}{4} \times \binom{4}{2} \times \frac{1}{2}$ ways of forming two distinct pairs of two items each, from a set of $n$ items.